# Prove that $\int_C \eta \neq 0$.

Tags: differential-topology

I hope I write down (a) correctly. For (b), I followed Amitesh Datta's suggestion, but I hope I well-justified my argument - did I?

On $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\omega = (\sin^4 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi(x + y))dx - \cos^2 \pi(x + y)dy$.

> (a) Show that $\omega$ is closed.

By definition, a $p$-form $\omega$ on $X$ is closed if $d\omega=0$. So
\begin{align*}
d\omega & = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\sin^4 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi(x + y)) \wedge dx - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cos^2 \pi(x + y) \wedge dy\\
& =  2 \pi \sin \pi(x + y)) \cos \pi (x+y) dy \wedge dx + 2 \pi \cos \pi(x + y) \sin \pi(x + y) dx \wedge dy\\
&=  0
\end{align*}

> (b) Let $\eta$ be the unique $1$-form on the torus $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$
>   such that $p^* \eta = \omega,$ where
>   $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to T^2$
>   is projection. The parametrized curve $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\gamma(\theta) = (2\theta, -3\theta)$
>   is a line whose image $C \subset T^2$
>   is an oriented circle. Prove that $\int_C \eta \neq 0$.
>   What is its sign?

By the theorem

> > **Change of Variable in $\mathbb{R}^k$.** Assume that $f: V \to U$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$ or $\mathbb{H}^k$, and let $\omega$ be an integrable $k$-form on $U$. Then
> >     $$\int_U \omega = \int_V f^*\omega.$$
> >     If $f$ reverses orientation, then
> >     $$\int_U \omega = - \int_V f^* \omega.$$

So for this problem, we have $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$, and I believe projection map is orientation preserving, and I know $p$ is diffeomorphism of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$. And I granted $\omega$ is integrable for it is composed of Trigonometric functions. Then I reached my conclusion that:

$$\int_C \eta = \int_\gamma p^* \eta = \int_\gamma \omega =  \int_\gamma (\sin^4 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi(x + y))dx - \cos^2 \pi(x + y)dy.$$
Carry out line integrals with $\gamma(\theta) = (2\theta, -3\theta):$
$$\int_\theta (\sin^4 \pi 2\theta + \sin^2 \pi \theta) 2d\theta + \cos^2 \pi \theta 3d \theta.$$

Hence, as long as $\theta \not\equiv 0$, $\int_C \eta \neq 0$, and it is positive.

Comment: Um, what is $\omega$?

Comment: Oh nooo!!! I didn't!! forget it!! @ChrisCulter

Comment: @WishingFish What is the range of values of $\theta$?

Comment: @AmiteshDatta, it is $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: $\int_{C} \eta=\int_{\gamma} \omega$

Comment: Thank you so much Amitesh, I followed your very wise hint and solved the question, hopefully.

Comment: You're welcome @WishingFish ! Let me know if there's anything else with which you'd like help.

Comment: You are so kind, thank you Amitesh! Aha, indeed there is! This is the last question for this problem, hope you could help me take a look at it! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451638/closed-and-exact

Comment: @WishingFish Thanks! I've answered your question. Let me know if it really does answer your question ...