# Closed and exact.

Tags: calculus, differential-topology

I tried this question, but I have no idea if I got it correctly.

On $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\omega = (\sin^4 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi(x + y))dx - \cos^2 \pi(x + y)dy$.

> Let $\eta$ be the unique $1$-form on the torus $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$
>   such that $p^* \eta = \omega,$ where
>   $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to T^2$
>   is projection. The parametrized curve $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\gamma(\theta) = (2\theta, -3\theta)$
>   is a line whose image $C \subset T^2$
>   is an oriented circle.  Is $\eta$ closed? Exact?

First I showed that $\omega$ is closed:
$$d\omega = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\sin^4 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi(x + y)) \wedge dx - 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cos^2 \pi(x + y) \wedge dy = 0$$

And then I showed $\int_C \eta \neq 0$:
$$\int_C \eta = \int_\gamma p^* \eta = \int_\gamma \omega =  \int_\gamma (\sin^4 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi(x + y))dx - \cos^2 \pi(x + y)dy.$$
Carry out line integrals with $\gamma(\theta) = (2\theta, -3\theta):$
$$\int_\theta (\sin^4 \pi 2\theta + \sin^2 \pi \theta) 2d\theta + \cos^2 \pi \theta 3d \theta.$$

Hence, as long as $\theta \not\equiv 0$, $\int_C \eta \neq 0$, and it is positive.

Assume $\eta$ i s exact, then $\eta = d\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. By Stokes' theorem, its integral over $C$ would be:
$$
\int_{C} \eta =\int_{C}  d\alpha = \int_{\partial C} \alpha = 0 \ .
$$
Since $\partial C = \emptyset$. This contradicts with the fact that $\int_{C} \eta \neq 0$.

$\eta$ is closed because
$$d\eta = d^2 \int_C \eta = d^2 \int_\gamma \omega = d \omega = 0.$$

- Agustí Roig's answer [checking if a 2-form is exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95295/checking-if-a-2-form-is-exact/95306#95306) is very helpful for me to think of this question.

> There is a standard embedding $i: T^2 \to S^1 \times S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ (determined by the formula $i \circ p(x, y) = (\cos 2 \pi x, \sin 2 \pi x, \cos 2 \pi y, \sin 2\pi y))$. Is there a closed form $\xi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $i^* \xi = \eta$?

My attempt following Amitesh Datta's hints:

> **Corollary.** $\mathbf{H}^p(\mathbb{R}^k) = 0$ if $k > 0$.

Hence, assume that there is a closed form $\xi$ on $\mathbb{R}$, according to the corollary, $\mathbf{H}^1(\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2) = 0$. Hence, $\xi$ is exact. But $i^* \xi = \eta$ would also be exact, contradict.

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Isnt $H^P(R^p) = \mathbb Z $ ( or whatever coefficient you are using) ? Since $R^p$ is orientable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want a more elementary proof but here's one that comes to mind:

**Theorem**

*Every closed form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is exact.*

If you're familiar with algebraic topology, then you might have seen this theorem already. If not, then can you prove it on your own? If so, then you've got an answer to your question (a corollary of the **Theorem**).

I hope this helps and I'm always happy to prove further hints if you encounter any difficulties in proving this **Theorem**!

Comment: Hey thanks Amitesh. How exciting that I am taking Algebraic Geometry this fall! So I don't have the knowledge at the time. Also, I have been wondering what make the previous question I attempted differ from this one? I noticed the domain of $p$ is $T^2$, and the domain of $i$ is $S^1 \times S^1 \subset \mathbb{R \times R}$. Does this differ $i$ from $p$ such that this **theorem** can be applied, and therefore $\xi$ is exact?

Comment: Hi Amitesh, I think I finally got it! Thank you so much for your generous help! However, I overlooked a tiny point hope to check with you: So if $\xi$ is exact, $i^* \xi $ would also be exact, since pullback is just change of variables right? Thank you very very much!

Comment: @WishingFish Yes, the pullback of an exact form is exact. (You may also wish to check that the pullback of a closed form is closed.)

Comment: @WishingFish The differential commutes with pull-backs, i.e., $f^{*}(d\omega)=df^{*}(\omega)$ for any smooth map $f:M\to N$ of smooth manifolds and any smooth form $\omega$ on $N$. A consequence is that pull-backs of closed forms are closed and pull-backs of exact forms are exact. Of course, this is what Potato was saying (awkward).

Comment: Thanks, @Potato , for your comment!

Comment: @AmiteshDatta No problem. I should have said what you said, but I was too lazy to write that all out...